# VSTS docker compose task

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to configure Continuous Delivery using VSTS and docker-compose and I would like to push it to the Azure Container Registry.
Here's my build definition on VSTS:
[image]

and I'm getting an error message on build result:

```
No such command: docker_compose
Commands:
build Build or rebuild services
bundle Generate a Docker bundle from the Compose file
config Validate and view the Compose file
create Create services
down Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes
events Receive real time events from containers
exec Execute a command in a running container
help Get help on a command
```

Do you know how can I handle it ?

UPDATE:
Here's my docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  ci-build:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0-1.1
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    working_dir: /src
    command: /bin/bash -c "dotnet restore ./Travelingowe.sln && dotnet publish ./Travelingowe.sln -c Release -o ./obj/Docker/publish"
```

Comment: Was it pushed to the registry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `docker-compose up`  use `up` only.  Just had the same problem myself.